# Random vs Shuffle

Tags: java, random, arraylist

I have an `ArrayList` which I want to grab a random value from. To do this I thought of two simple methods:

Method 1: Uses `Random` to generate a random number between 0 and the size of the `ArrayList` and then use that number for `arrayList.get(x)`

Method 2: Use `arrayList.shuffle()` and then `arrayList.get(0)`.

Is one method preferable to the other in terms of randomness, I know it is impossible for one to be truly random but I want the result to be as random as possible.

EDIT: I only need one value from that `ArrayList`

Comment: Both approaches would be pretty acceptable, I'd think.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It depends on the context.

Benefits of shuffling:

- Once a shuffle, then just sequential grabbing
- No repeated values

Benefits of randomizing:

- Great for a small amount of values
- Can repeat values

Comment: I made an edit stating I only need one value, and I'll only need that value once.

Comment: @rsay3: will you need another randomized value with or without taking the previous value in regards? As in: can the next value that has to be chosen be already chosen once? If it doesn't matter: see how many you want. If you still only need a small amount then the answer is randomizing. If you need a small amount but unique values then you can take randomizing as well with a separate list and some if statements, but you should only do that if it is too cumbersome to just shuffle the entire list and be done with it.

Comment: I mean I won't need any other value. I just want one value from the ArrayList, after that the section of code is completed

Comment: @rsay3: then you should simply pick a random value.

Answer (score 5):

To answer your direct question: neither one of these is "more random" than the other. The results of the two methods are statistically indistinguishable. After all, the first step in shuffling an array is (basically) picking a number between `0` and `N-1` (where `N` is the length of the array) and moving that element into the first position.

That being said, there are valid reasons to pick one or the other, depending on your specific needs. [Jeroen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21714587/56541) summarizes those well.

Answer (score 1):

I would say the random number option is the best (Method 1).

Shuffling the objects takes up extra resources, because it has to move all of the objects around in the ArrayList, where generating a random number gives you the same effect without needing to use CPU time to cycle through array elements!

Also, be sure to generate a number between 0 and the size MINUS ONE. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you just want one random selection, use Method 1. If you want to get a sequence of random selections with no duplicates, use Method 2.

Answer (score 1):

Randomness depends on two factors, the algorithm (a.k.a the "generator") and the seed.

- **What generators does each method use?**

The second overload of `Collections.Shuffle()` actually accepts a seeded `Random`. If you choose the default overload, it uses a `Random` *anyway*, as specified in the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html). You're using a `Random` no matter what.

- **Are the generators seeded differently?**

Another look at Random in the Javadoc shows that it is seeded by with some time value unless you specify a seed. Shuffle doesn't specify a time if you look at the implementation. You're using the default seed unless you specify one.

Because both use `Random` and both use the same default seed, they are **equally random**.

- **Which one has a higher time complexity?**

Shuffling a list is O(n) (the Javadoc for Shuffle actually specifies linear time). The time complexity of Random.nextInt() is O(1). Obviously, the latter is faster in a case where only one value is needed.